# TestCafe: Testing a Page Opening a PDF in a New Tab

Tags: pdf, testing, automation, e2e-testing, testcafe

Part of the web application I am testing is to click a button, which normally opens a PDF in a new tab. This enables the user to go forward in the application. The PDF can be ignored.

Currently, my strategy is to click the button and then navigate back using ClientFunction. TestCafe successfully opens the PDF when the button is clicked, but it is opened in the same tab and the test is then stuck. Navigating back changes the URL, but the PDF is still displayed.

```js
    const goBack = ClientFunction(() => window.history.back())

    await this.t.click(this.button)
    await this.t.wait(10000)

    await goBack()
```

Is TestCafe currently able to bypass this issue, as I don't need to actually do anything with the PDF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TestCafe allows testing html pages, but not PDF files. So, you can check the generated link to the PDF file as a string without actually following this link. For example:

```
const overrideWindowOpen = ClientFunction(() => {
    window.open = function (url) {
        window.__lastWindowOpenUrl = url;
    };
});
const getResultUrl = ClientFunction(() => window.__lastWindowOpenUrl);

await overrideWindowOpen();
await t
    .click(this.button)
    .expect(getResultUrl()).eql('http://example.com/path/to/PDF/93023813-0984-1');
```

See also: [Multiple Browser Windows](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/multiple-browser-windows.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you expand your explanation a bit with the overriding?  Would I be able to prevent the application to open the PDF, which would allow me to continue the test without breaking it by accessing the PDF?

Comment: Hey @Artem, how would you save the actual window.open function as a backup in another ClientFunction?